# Quit an App designer GUI using a code - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

How can I quit an App designer GUI using a button?

I tried this and it does not work:

```
function QuitButtonPushed(app, event)
          fig = uifigure;
          selection = uiconfirm(fig,'Close software?','Quit', 'Icon','warning');  
          switch selection
          case 'Yes'
          app.delete;
          case 'No'
         return 
        end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The switch case should be with `'OK'` and `'Cancel'` and not `'Yes'`, `'No'`.

It is also recommended to pass `app.UIFigure` instead of using `fig = uifigure;`:

```
selection = uiconfirm(app.UIFigure,'Close software?','Quit', 'Icon','warning');

switch selection
    case 'OK'
        app.delete();
    case 'Cancel'
        return
end
```